# Should I embed a view controller's view within a new view?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

When adding an external view controller to an existing one in the Storyboard you would use a "container view". When adding one programatically you are presented with the option of creating a new `UIView` to embed the external VC's view within (replicating a container view) or simply just adding the external VC's `.view` directly into the existing one.

Which is considered the better practise here when doing this programatically? Does one have a different effect than the other on performance or reliability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a container view in Storyboard automates the process of:

- instantiate view controller
- add as childViewController
- add its view as a subview of the container view (which is a subview of the main view)

Adding a child view controller via code is the same process:

- instantiate view controller
- add as childViewController
- add its view as a subview of the current view, *or* as a subview of another subview of the current view

The other benefit of using a container view in Storyboard is that you get a visual design interface.

Of course, some people don't like Storyboard / IB, and prefer code-only approaches.

So really, whichever method best suits your needs and development style.

Comment: Your explanation of what is happening when a container view is added via the storyboard was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much.